# How to access/report to Game Center from non BaseGameActivity

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have a loader which response on signIn/login to Google play game center.

After the loader finish, I start new activity, `GameActivity` which I don't want hit to `extends` `BaseGameActivity`, But I need this activity to report score and show leaderboard.

How can I access `ApiClient` from non `BaseGameActivity`?

If I was extends from `BaseGameActivity` I would access `getApiClient()`.

Thanks in advance!